# Rename the field of a JsonUnwrapped field

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to use Jackson to deserialize the following json structure

```
{
  "name" : "Alex",
  "favoriteNumbers" : ["42", "9"]
}
```

into the following class structure

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private ListOfNumbers favoriteNumbers;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ListOfNumbers getFavoriteNumbers() {
        return favoriteNumbers;
    }

    public void setFavoriteNumbers(ListOfNumbers favoriteNumbers) {
        this.favoriteNumbers = favoriteNumbers;
    }
}

class ListOfNumbers {
    private List<String> list;

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

If I use @JsonUnwrapped on Person.favoriteNumbers, I can only deserialize the following:

```
{
  "name" : "Alex",
  "list" : ["42", "9"]
}
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I do not want add @JsonProperty to ListOfNumbers.list, because I need to use a different name depending on the field referencing ListOfNumbers. E.g. a class Company with ListOfNumbers phoneNumbers should be able to deserialize the following:

```
{
  "companyName" : "MyCompany",
  "phoneNumbers" : ["42343243", "234235239"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonUnwrapped` is used to unwrap values of objects during serialization.So use this annotation will make attribute `favoriteNumbers` -> `List`. Just like your post outcome.
So the simple way is :

```
class ListOfNumbers {
//private List<String> list; ->//private List<String> favoriteNumbers;

public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

Comment: Say I have also a class Company with ListOfNumbers phoneNumbers. How can I both deserialize phoneNumbers for Company and favoriteNumbers for Person? In your suggestion favoriteNumbers is now fixed to ListOfNumbers class, but I want it dynamic and depending on the field referencing ListOfNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use @JsonProperty directly with an extra method in the same class. Does is not solve ur problem?

tl;dr

```
@JsonIgnore
private ListOfNumbers companyNumbers;

@JsonProperty("phoneNumbers")
public List<String> getPhoneNumbers() {
  return companyNumbers.getList();
}

@JsonProperty("phoneNumbers")
public void setPhoneNumbers(List<String> phoneNumbers) {
  this.companyNumbers = new ListOfNumbers(phoneNumbers);
}
```

Full example

```
package org.json.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

  public static class Person {
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    private ListOfNumbers favoriteNumbers;

    public Person() {
      favoriteNumbers = new ListOfNumbers(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    @JsonProperty("favoriteNumbers")
    public List<String> getPhoneNumbers() {
      return favoriteNumbers.getList();
    }

    @JsonProperty("favoriteNumbers")
    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<String> phoneNumbers) {
      this.favoriteNumbers = new ListOfNumbers(phoneNumbers);
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public ListOfNumbers getFavoriteNumbers() {
      return favoriteNumbers;
    }

    public void setFavoriteNumbers(ListOfNumbers favoriteNumbers) {
      this.favoriteNumbers = favoriteNumbers;
    }
  }

  public static class Company {
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    private ListOfNumbers companyNumbers;

    public Company() {
      companyNumbers = new ListOfNumbers(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    @JsonProperty("phoneNumbers")
    public List<String> getPhoneNumbers() {
      return companyNumbers.getList();
    }

    @JsonProperty("phoneNumbers")
    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<String> phoneNumbers) {
      this.companyNumbers = new ListOfNumbers(phoneNumbers);
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public ListOfNumbers getCompanyNumbers() {
      return companyNumbers;
    }

    public void setCompanyNumbers(ListOfNumbers companyNumbers) {
      this.companyNumbers = companyNumbers;
    }
  }


  public static class ListOfNumbers {
    private List<String> list;

    ListOfNumbers(List<String> list) {
      this.list = list;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
      return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
      this.list = list;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    doPersonSample();
    doCompanySample();
  }

  private static void doCompanySample() throws JsonProcessingException {
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    var person = new Company();
    person.name = "stavang Ltd.";
    person.getCompanyNumbers().getList().add("26");
    person.getCompanyNumbers().getList().add("4");

    var toJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
    System.out.println(toJson);

    var fromJson = "{\n" +
        "  \"name\" : \"stavang Ltd.\",\n" +
        "  \"phoneNumbers\" : [\"26\", \"4\"]\n" +
        "}";

    var deserializedCompany = mapper.readValue(fromJson, Company.class);

    System.out.println(deserializedCompany.getCompanyNumbers().getList());
  }

  private static void doPersonSample() throws JsonProcessingException {
    var mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    var person = new Person();
    person.name = "Alex";
    person.getFavoriteNumbers().getList().add("42");
    person.getFavoriteNumbers().getList().add("9");

    var toJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
    System.out.println(toJson);

    var fromJson = "{\n" +
        "  \"name\" : \"Alex\",\n" +
        "  \"favoriteNumbers\" : [\"42\", \"9\"]\n" +
        "}";

    var deserializedPerson = mapper.readValue(fromJson, Person.class);

    System.out.println(deserializedPerson.favoriteNumbers.getList());
  }
}
```